# How to let Visual Studio accept broken XMLs for Unit Testing

Tags: c#, xml, visual-studio, unit-testing

I am working on a project in Visual Studio that reads XML files. I want to write a Unit Test to make sure invalid XMLs are handled correctly. But when adding an invalid XML to VS it shows error messages indicating that my XML is not valid. My solution still builds but I would still like to get rid of these error messages since in this case they are not really errors.

Is there a way to tell Visual Studio to ignore errors for this specific XML file? In general I like that VS checks my XML files but in this case I don't want it.

This is the XML I am using for testing:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="us-ascii"?>
<ADI>
    <BreakMe>
    <Author>Arne</Author>
    <Wurst>Sandy</Wurst>
    <Date>2015-09-24T07:35:28Z</Date>
</ADI>
```

Thank you for your help!

Comment: If I recall correctly, the errors only show up if the file is open in the IDE.  Could you simply close the XML file?  If you need it open, just open in a different editor or viewer?

Comment: Unless you wrote your own XML parser why are you testing invaild xml.

Comment: @jglouie: yes, you're right. Didn't expect it to be so easy. Closing the file solves the problem.
@ Matthew Whited: I'm not directly testing the XML parser but a function that uses it. So I want to check if this function handles the occurring error as expected.

Comment: @洋葱头 Glad it helped.  I just added it as an answer so that people could find the solution quicker.  Could you mark it as correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just close the XML file in the IDE.  The errors will go away.

If you want to view the XML file while you are in your solution, open it in a different editor or viewer.  You may need to open it in a generic text editor because some XML editors/viewers will complain to you that it's invalid as well and refuse to open it.

For what it's worth, this is a common annoyance.  I just helped my coworker with this problem for SQL files.